# Google Reader API?

Tags: rss, google-reader, atom-feed

Is there any Google Reader API that I can plug in to? I building a clean RSS/Atom reader in PHP and would love to get all the goodies from Google Reader like the history of a feed, able to add comments to each feed item, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've built some google reader integration in python but I can share some of the api knowledge so you can get started.  output=json is also available for all.

Login: `https  www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin`

```
POST &email=email&passwd=password&service=reader&source=appname&continue=http://www.google.com
```

from the response grab Auth=

Next hit: www.google.com/reader/api/0/token

```
HEADER Authorization=GoogleLogin auth=$Auth
```

That response becomes $token for the session.

From there it's just hitting some url's always passing that auth header and including the token in the querystring or post.

Gets a list of your subscriptions: www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list?output=xml

To modify subscriptions this is the base url plus some post data for the action to perform

```
www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/edit?pos=0&client=$source
```

POST to add: `s=$streams&t=$title&T=$token&ac=subscribe`

POST to remove: `s=$stream&T=$token&ac=unsubscribe`

The $stream is generally feed/$feedurl like this for techcrunch, feed/http:// feeds.feedburner.com/Techcrunch

Sorry had to mangle some of the urls cause i don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be "easy" for me use the GR API for my PHP RSS Client. Do you have a demo of what you have built =)

Comment: Best example is this video I posted on youtube, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWnb7o0utfA

Comment: Is there a way to add a subscription in Google Reader using the API?

Thanks!

Comment: Would this approach still work after Google Reader was discontinued?

Answer (score 2):

this is a working example in python:

```
import urllib, urllib2
import json, pprint

email, password = 'jose@gmail.com', 'nowayjose'
clientapp, service = 'reader', 'reader'

params = urllib.urlencode({'Email': email, 'Passwd': password, 'source': clientapp, 'service': service})
req = urllib2.Request(url='https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin', data=params)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)

for line in f.readlines():
  if line[0:5] == 'Auth=':
    auth=line[5:]

root = "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/"

req = urllib2.Request(root + "token")
req.add_header('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth=' + auth)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
token = f.readlines()[0]

# get user id
req = urllib2.Request(root + "user-info?output=json&token="+token)
req.add_header('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth=' + auth)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
dictUser = json.loads(f.read())
user_id = dictUser["userId"]
print "user_id",user_id

req = urllib2.Request(root + "subscription/list?output=json&token="+token)
req.add_header('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth=' + auth)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)

# for line in f.readlines():
#     print line
dictSubscriptions = json.loads(f.read())

# pprint.pprint(dictSubscriptions)
# print the first 3 subscription titles
for i in dictSubscriptions["subscriptions"][0:2]:
    print i["title"]

req = urllib2.Request("http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?output=json&token="+token)
req.add_header('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth=' + auth)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
dictUnread = json.loads(f.read())
# pprint.pprint(dictUnread)
# print the first 3 unread folders
for i in dictUnread["unreadcounts"][0:3]:
    print i["count"], i["id"]

# this returns all starred items as xml
req = urllib2.Request("http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/"+user_id+"/state/com.google/starred?token="+token)
req.add_header('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth=' + auth)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
starredItems = f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Reader has feeds for user's. I guess you could use those. Also, they're [PubSubHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) ready, so you will get comments/likes... as soon as they happen.

Also, as of July 1st 2013, Google Reader is no more. Options for replacements include [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com).

Comment: Yupp, know that =) But my users should be able to add/edit/remove feeds from within my app, and that feed should work like in Google Reader with the ability to comment, add notes, share, etc.