# Import feeds from Google Reader

Tags: rss, google-reader

I am making a webapp that uses feeds to get website urls. I want to make it so users can click a button and it will automatically add all of the feeds from their google reader accounts. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the answer to [Google Reader API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063513/google-reader-api)

Comment: I think my case is a little different. That seems to pertain to using google's API's to make an RSS feeder easily using Javascript. I want to be able to grab from google's database a list or something like that of all of the feeds that a given user already has in their Google Reader. Sorta like with facebook's APIs you can grab a list of things people like, I wanna grab a list of feed urls.

Comment: it's about what HTTP requests you need to make - not at all specific to javascript.  and halfway down it says "Gets a list of your subscriptions: www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list?output=xml" which is the URL you make a request to with the appropriate auth header set

Comment: that's exactly what that answer does.  After I wrote that I put together a tutoril for mobiletuts using php.  You can check it out here, http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/building-a-mobile-web-application-with-the-google-reader-api/

Comment: Wow...I'm sorry, thanks a million for the help. I'll look closer next time. My bad guys.